# Insertions in database inside a controller's method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I want to do two insert operations in the database inside a controller's method :

```
a = A.new(:dog_id => b.id, ...)
a.save
b = B.new(:cat_id => a.id , ... )
b.save
```

How do I do this since I need the id of a in b and id of b in a?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A, B, C? What are you tring to do? If you have a `Category` model that has many dogs and a `Dog` model that belongs to a category you just have the categories and when you create a new dog you assign the category simply using `dog.category = Category.find_by_name(category_name)`.

...But I suspect you have some kind of many-to-many relationship between a dog and a category, in that case you need another model and database table...

**UPDATE**: Still doesn't make any sense to me, try to provide further details...another idea is to create the two objects and then update:

```
# Create the two objects
a = A.create
b = B.create
# Update a with the B id
a.dog = b
a.save
# Update b with the A id
b.cat = a
a.save
```

But again, you should really update your answer to explain what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I want to do an insert operation in table A and one in table B but I need the id that was inserted into the table B as an attribute to make the insert in table A.

Comment: I've updated the answer but I suggest you to update you question to explain better what you really want to do

Answer (score 2):

Setup the Models A + B with the correct associations first

```
Model Cat
  has_one :dog
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :dog

Model Dog
  has_one :cat
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :cat
```

I'm basing the models off the code you've provided where each instance of A can only have one B and vice versa. You can also use belongs_to instead [old explanation from 2006](http://duanesbrain.blogspot.co.uk/2006/05/ruby-on-rails-hasone-versus-belongsto.html)

Accepts_nested_attributes_for allows you to pass the attributes for the associated model in the params for the original model [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)
Note that this relationship can only accept a single relationship between A and B (Cat and Dog) if you need many_to_many try [has_and_belongs_to_many](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

In the controller build the instances of the models and set up their associations.

```
this_cat = Cat.new(cat_attributes{dog_attributes})

this_cat.save!
```

Pretty sure there's a few ways of doing this but as Aldo says a bit more detail on the question code would help clear up some of the associations - since I might be getting the wrong idea of how you want this to function.

Another way without using accepts_nested_attributes_for would be to build each instance of A and B save one of them, do the association then save them both.

```
this_cat = Cat.new(cat_attributes)
this_dog = Dog.new(dog_attributes)
this_dog.save!    
this_cat.dog = this_dog
this_cat.save!
this_dog.save!
```